# Where to find Access log for mastekey access in Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: python, python-2.7, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-log-analytics

Can you please help me understand where can i find logs of all activities using the masterkey to access CosmosDB/ DocumentDB azure.

Background:
All i can find in the logs is userid who accessed the document db on azure. We also hava a script in python using Pydocumentdb which uses masterkey to access data from Azure Cosmos DB. But none of it can be seen in logs.

Thanks

Comment: Hi,any updates now?

Comment: Hi I have been sick off, I will confirm the answer by Friday.

Comment: Sure! Any concern please feel free to let me know.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Diagnostic logging` in Azure Cosmos DB enables you to perform this monitoring how and when your databases are accessed.

Please click `Diagnostic logs` in the left navigation, and then click `Turn on diagnostics` in your azure cosmos db.

[image]

You can store log files in `azure account`,stream to `eventhub` or send to `azure analytics`

[image]

Logs are made available in your account `two hours` from the time the Azure Cosmos DB operation was made. It's up to you to manage your logs in your storage account.

Individual blobs are stored as text, formatted as a `JSON` blob.

```
{
    "records":
    [
        {
           "time": "Fri, 23 Jun 2017 19:29:50.266 GMT",
           "resourceId": "contosocosmosdb",
           "category": "DataPlaneRequests",
           "operationName": "Query",
           "resourceType": "Database",
           "properties": {"activityId": "05fcf607-6f64-48fe-81a5-f13ac13dd1eb",`
           "userAgent": "documentdb-dotnet-sdk/1.12.0 Host/64-bit MicrosoftWindowsNT/6.2.9200.0 AzureSearchIndexer/1.0.0",`
           "resourceType": "Database","statusCode": "200","documentResourceId": "",`
           "clientIpAddress": "13.92.241.0","requestCharge": "2.260","collectionRid": "",`
           "duration": "9250","requestLength": "72","responseLength": "209", "resourceTokenUserRid": ""}
        }
    ]
}
```

Please refer to more details from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/logging).

***Update Answer:***

According to my observation, the logs in Azure Cosmos DB do not distinguish between requests by using `Master key` or `Resource Token`.

However, I would like to provide you with a workaround.

You know, `Python Document DB SDK` actually is [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/).

So,you could send your HTTP requests to the azure server through the `reverse proxy`,such as [Nginx](https://nginx.org/en/).

You could judge which access method by the format of request URL, and log it in the `reverse proxy` layer.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Hi Jay,I turned on the Diagnostic Logging. I can see two folders in storage account under logs Operation Logs and Dataplane request logs. My question is where and how do i find request logs for  document DB which were requested using master key for DocumentDB. I can find the user access logs but not Masterkey access logs.

Comment: @PrafulMattoo Hi,Praful. Please see my update answer.

Comment: This helps Thanks a lot. I will accept the answer. Have a great day :)